# Textbox hint in ZK

Tags: textbox, zk, hint

I want to have a textbox with a hint. For example, if that textbox triggers a search, I want it to initially have a "Search" text greyed out and when the user starts typing for it to disappear. How do I achieve this in ZK? 
In android I think I had the hint tag, so I want something similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found it's called placeholder.